# Remove internal array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to remove an internal array from an array. Actually, the array is obtained by decoding `JSON`, and can go upto `n levels`. I need to remove an internal array from an array of its parent based on the key which is dynamic. Below is the code that I have tried referring to answers on php arrays.

```
$quotationHistory = json_decode($quotationCollection->getHistory(), true);
$quotationId = 5;
foreach ($quotationHistory as $sales_id => $history) {
    foreach($history as $quotationIdValue => $values) {
        if ($quotationId == $quotationIdValue) {
            unset ($history[$quotationIdValue]);
        }
    }
}
```

sample:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3
                            [1] => 8490.0000
                            [2] => 21-10-2016 11:43:18am
                            [3] => 24-11-2016 11:43:18am
                            [4] => 199
                            [5] => rtg
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 12
                            [1] => 8490.0000
                            [2] => 21-10-2016 11:43:40am
                            [3] => 24-11-2016 11:43:18am
                            [4] => 199
                            [5] => rtg
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 45
                            [1] => 8490.0000
                            [2] => 21-10-2016 11:43:54am
                            [3] => 24-11-2016 11:43:18am
                            [4] => 199
                            [5] => rtg
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11
                            [1] => 8490.0000
                            [2] => 21-10-2016 11:44:04am
                            [3] => 24-11-2016 11:43:18am
                            [4] => 199
                            [5] => rtg
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 54
                            [1] => 8490.0000
                            [2] => 21-10-2016 11:44:16am
                            [3] => 24-11-2016 11:43:18am
                            [4] => 199
                            [5] => rtg
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now, I want to remove the second level data with key = 5

Comment: Are you sure you passed in the `if` condition ? Is your `$quotationId` variable correctly initialized? Do a dump of your `$quotationId` and your array. Add a trace in the `if` condition.

Comment: Please format correctly the "sample" you just added, it's unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better do the unset on the original array:

```
$quotationHistory = json_decode($quotationCollection->getHistory(), true);            
foreach($quotationHistory as $sales_id => $history) {
    foreach($history as $quotationIdValue => $values) {
        if($quotationId == $quotationIdValue){
            unset($quotationHistory[$sales_id][$quotationIdValue]);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason is that the internal array is passed as a copy. But you can also specify an assignation by reference:

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference ([official Php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)).

```
$quotationHistory = json_decode($quotationCollection->getHistory(), true);            
foreach($quotationHistory as $sales_id => &$history) {
    foreach($history as $quotationIdValue => &$values) {
        if($quotationId == $quotationIdValue){
            unset($$history[$quotationIdValue]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The item is not getting removed.

Comment: Are you sure you passed in the `if` condition ? Is your `$quotationId` variable correctly initialized? Do a dump of your `$quotationId` and your array. Add a trace in the `if` condition.

Comment: I have added a sample array in my question

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want a recursive iterator since the return can be any level down in the array *(presumably that's what you mean by `n levels`)*. One note, it would remove any key with the same value so it would remove any key with `5`. You would be better to recurse to remove the key based on value `rtg`:

```
$arr    =   array(
    'one'=>array(
        'one'=>'and a half',
        'two'=>array(
            'three'=>'three and a half'
        )
    )
);

function recurse($array,$remove=false)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if($key != $remove){
                if(is_array($value)) {
                    $new[$key]  =   recurse($value,$remove);
                }
                else
                    $new[$key]  =   $value;
            }
        }

        return $new;
    }

# Run the iterator to remove the key named "three"
print_r(recurse($arr,'three'));
```

If you need to search by value, this should work:

```
function recurseValue($array,$remove=false)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {
                $new[$key]  =   recurseValue($value,$remove);
            }
            else {
                if($value != $remove){
                    $new[$key]  =   $value;
                }
            }
        }

        return $new;
    }
# Run the iterator to remove the key with the value named "Three and a half"
print_r(recurseValue($arr,'three and a half'));
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [one] => Array
        (
            [one] => and a half
            [two] => 
        )

)
```

This last option will normalize the array to one level so you can loop over it normally:

```
function recurseArray($array,&$new,$bkey = false)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {
                recurseArray($value,$new,$key);
            }
            else {
                $new[$bkey][]   =   $value;
            }
        }
    }

$new = array();
recurseArray($arr,$new);
print_r($new);
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 8490.0000
            [2] => 21-10-2016 11:43:18am
            [3] => 24-11-2016 11:43:18am
            [4] => 199
            [5] => rtg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 8490.0000
            [2] => 21-10-2016 11:43:18am
            [3] => 24-11-2016 11:43:18am
            [4] => 199
            [5] => rtg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 8490.0000
            [2] => 21-10-2016 11:43:18am
            [3] => 24-11-2016 11:43:18am
            [4] => 199
            [5] => rtg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 8490.0000
            [2] => 21-10-2016 11:43:18am
            [3] => 24-11-2016 11:43:18am
            [4] => 199
            [5] => rtg
        )
)
```

Comment: I want to remove the value based on key = 5

Comment: Can it be at depth?

Comment: No, it is on the second level as it is in the sample. The depth `n` is for some sensitive data, if available.

Comment: Oh, then just do a double loop then as noted in the other answer. Recursing is only if you don't know what depth the target array is at.

Comment: I did one last one, if you are interested. It will flatten the array to one level so you only have to do one `foreach` on the `$new` array in my example. It's probably a bit overkill, but it might give you some ideas.

Comment: Actually, I just need to remove the item and then again, convert it to json and save back to database